# Does Dubai impose prison time or even the death penalty for victims of rape?

Tags: sexual-abuse, dubai

In Dubai, if a person becomes a  victim of a rape, and it's clear that s/he was forced (that is, the victim is not being suspected or accused of voluntary extra-marital sex), could the justice in Dubai impose a prison sentence or even the death sentence?

Does this happen, or is it simply a theoretical possibility?

[Briton who reported rape in Dubai could face jail for extramarital sex](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/nov/17/briton-reported-rape-dubai-extramarital-sex-charge)

Comment: Hello there and welcome to Skeptics! Your question is really interesting, but by this site's rules, you need to cite the source from which you based your question. Could you add links to where you got this information?

Comment: I'm confused. You wrote that you're asking about instances where "the victim is not being suspected or accused of extra-marital sex", then linked to a story about someone who _is_ accused of extra-marital sex.

Comment: That story actually says that other women have been imnprisoned for being raped - What more information do you require to show if this is true oir not?

Comment: Look at the article more carefully.  The issue is not a matter of being jailed for being raped.  Rather, by claiming rape you are admitting sex with the person.  If the rape charge can't be supported you have in effect admitted to extramarital sex--a crime.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I want to be able to reopen this question, but at the moment it is a bit confusing. The only claim provided is that it *has* happened to one woman. So is the question "is the news report true?" It is too early to tell.

Comment: The newspaper report does not say that the alleged extramarital sex was with the alleged rapists; it may have been a separate incident that came out during the investigation. It also doesn't say that the alleged extramarital sex was clearly forced. It may be that the police have evidence that it was consensual. I am **not** denying a rape took place. I am saying that the contents of this article do not make the claim that the question title is making, so we need to fix the question or find a better source.

Comment: @Mark: It is worth noting that the *question* asks about Dubai, but the Australian woman and South African woman were not jailed in Dubai.